# Change bootstrap navigation class when scroll on other div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to make a little portfolio for my fcc project.
i want my nav links change there active class when the the target div is in focus.
i use bootstrap in this code
[Here is my codepen link](https://codepen.io/kuyaMacoy/pen/KgAoNX) . please help

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right link">
        <li><a href="#about" class="links">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

And my Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});/* end of clickto scroll function */



var scroll_start = 0;
var startchange = $('#button-down');
var offset = startchange.offset();
if (startchange.length){
$(document).scroll(function() { 
  scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
      $(".navbar").css('background-color', '#333');

   } else {
      $('.navbar').css('background-color', 'transparent');
   }
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: search the bootstrap documentation it has a plugin exactly for what you need http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Answer (score 0):

Search the bootstrap documentation it has a plugin exactly for what you need :[affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Answer (score 0):

What you are designing is a one page portfolio, so that when user clicks on "My Project" she will be scrolled to "My projects" section.

Try [Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) from bootstrap. adding custom classes to scrollspy will help.

If you are in hurry, use [this template](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/) and then stylize as per your need.